# function not run again if status === false

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

iam trying to run my function again if the status of my json false but its not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function checkIfCompleted(){
        $('.btn').click( function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = "https://localhost/check/1";
            $.ajax({
               url: url,
               success: function(response) {
                 if(response.status === false){
                     checkIfCompleted();
                 }else{
                     alert(done);
                 }

                },
            });
        });
    }
    checkIfCompleted();
});
```

Comment: You are just binding the event handler again so that means the button now has two clicks.... So you either need to trigger click on the button OR pull the Ajax code out into a function.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `json`. Also `checkIfCompleted()` adds a new `click` handler every time it is executed - and nothing more. That `$.ajax()` call is only executed if someone clicks on an element with the class `btn`

Comment: Also you might get stuck in an infinite loop if the call keeps returning `false`...

Comment: yes i want my action to start running if i click on btn and check if the status is false so its run again till it be true

Comment: `response.status` is likely a number corresponding to an HTTP status code (and will therefore never be `false`?).

Comment: `console.log(url);` and check the result first

Answer (score 0):

You are adding click multiple times to the button, you are not rerunning the Ajax call

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function checkIfCompleted(cnt) {
    var url = "https://localhost/check/1";
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.status === false) {
          if (cnt >= 5) {
            throw new Error('too many retries');
          } else {
            checkIfCompleted(++cnt);
          }
        } else {
          alert(done);
        }

      },
    });

  }
  $('.btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkIfCompleted(0);
  });

});
```